# Need help configuring nginx with 2 different hostnames that support wildcard subdomains

Tags: nginx

my first server block is

```
server{
    listen       80;
    server_name  xxx.to;
        server_name  *.xxx.to;

root   /data/xxx/public_html/;
}
```

and second is

```
server{
    listen       80;
    server_name  yyy.to;
        server_name  *.yyy.to;

root   /data/yyy/public_html/;
}
```

But when i bind a CNAME link subdomain.yyy.to
its redirect subdomian.xxx.to not subdomain.yyy.to

Answer (score 2):

You should try to have only one server_name directive but with different values like:

```
server{
    listen       80;
    server_name  xxx.to *.xxx.to;

root   /data/xxx/public_html/;
}

server{
    listen       80;
    server_name  yyy.to *.yyy.to;

root   /data/yyy/public_html/;
}
```

Comment: its not working same problem.I want to handle two different domian  wild card subdomain with singal nginx server.